# C sharp code cleanup : resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I just used [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and it made me feel as if i don't know how to code at all in C#; it gave me a lot of suggestions; few of them are:

1) `SomeObject o = new SomeObject();`

Resharper will convert to :

```
var o = new SomeObject()
```

2) `this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);`

to

```
this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
```

3) convert my variables and putting _ in front of all instance variables.

4) Removing class parent's name. I tested this on Silverlight.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
```

to

```
public partial class MainPage
```

5) replace instance variable

```
 this.variable = somevalue
```

to

```
 variable = somevalue
```

Are all of these really necessary? Is it really going to affect the efficiency of my program? I mean what good is it going to do by replacing my class names with `var` keyword. After all `var` is also replaced with class name at compile time. Is it doing because it *has* been programmed to do or do these things really affect in some or another way?

Comment: I really doubt about point 4. Its breaking inheritance.

Comment: @Madhur: It would only do that if the other piece of the partial class was declared to be inheriting from UserControl.

Comment: @Madhur: +1 on Joe's comment. Don't forget that this class is "Partial".

Comment: @madhur it's a partial class - resharper will ensure there is no duplication of declarations.

Comment: Thanks all for the clarification

Comment: @xOn :- Yes it ensures but i feel readability is improved by letting that class name remain as it is. We can just go to the top of the file and atleast see what class it is inherting from. After all that code is `most` often generated by Visual Studio. It takes out mistake even in Visual Studio's auto generated code :d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behaviour is all configurable in ReSharper settings. There are a mix of code clean-up rules (e.g. whether to replace usages with var - I don't!), code style rules (e.g. variable naming) and formatting rules (e.g. how to place braces).

I wrote an article that gives an overview of these settings and how they can be used to shape coding standards and then be automatically applied via code cleanup:

http://gojisoft.com/blog/2010/05/10/coding-standards-using-resharper/

At the end of the day a lot of them are concerned with coding style and removing redundant code, they have no affect on the compiled code. You can configure many of them to suit you or your team's coding style.

Answer (score 5):

> Are all of these really necessary?

None are necessary.

> Is it really going to affect the efficiency of my program?

It will not impact the compiled code in a way that changes performance or semantics at all.

> I mean what good is it going to do by replacing my class names with `var` keyword.  After all var is also replaced with class name at compile time.

More readable code.

> Is it doing because it has been programmed to do or do these things really affect in some or another way?

Yes. These are configurable if you don't like them.

1) Is okay.

```
SomeObject o = new SomeObject();
```

The first `SomeObject` is redundant and useless and with `var` it's no less readable and arguably more readable. Addtionally for complex definitions like

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

it's way more readable than the alternative. However, this can be overdone. For example

```
string s = "s";
```

is preferred over

```
var s = "s";
```

as is

```
var i = 5;
```

over

```
int i = 5;
```

Note that

```
var i = 2147483648;
```

is really bad because it's not immediately clear what the type of `i` is. For non-complex definitions I prefer using explicit typing over implicit typing. Additionally, sometimes you want to say

```
IFoo foo = new Foo();
```

to explicitly type `foo` an `IFoo` whereas `var` would type it as a `Foo`.

2) Less code is in general better code.

3) I hate this suggestion. I hate the leading underscore. I use the usual naming convention for my member variables and I preface them with `this` for clarity. I would turn this one off.

```
public SomeObject(string name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

is more readable than

```
public SomeObject(string name) {
    _name = name;
}
```

in my opinion.

4) Wait, why is it doing this? I'm a little confused by this one. Because it's partial and another part of the class definition has the inheritance? I can't imagine it's doing this in a case where it changes the semantics. I would turn this one off.

5) I don't like this one (see 3.)

Comment: Regarding #4: As pointed out in the comments on the OP, ReSharper only suggests this when the base class is declared by another part of the partial class. In this case, I can pretty much guarantee we're seeing the code-behind of a WPF UserControl, whose XAML frontend declares the base class.

Comment: @djacobson: Ah, thanks. Personally, I think it's more clear with the redundant statement of the base class.

Comment: Re #4, I always remove the redundant base class. Makes it easier if I later want to change my Window to a UserControl, or my UserControl to a Page -- I only have to change the XAML and everything just works. If you kept the redundant ": UserControl" you would need to change it both places (XAML and codebehind). DRY.

Answer (score 3):

They are not necessary.

They follow a coding standard set by resharper. The nice thing is that you can configure the coding standard to your own ways.

The beautiful thing about resharper though is that you end up learning different ways of doing something you always did in a certain manner.

Answer (score 2):

All of those changes should have no effect whatsoever on the compiled CIL code - they're just ReSharper's opinion on readability of the C# code itself.

You can adjust all of those settings to suit your or your department's needs.  For the most part, it's a matter of personal preference.